# Zenbox validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have imported zedbox script from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.zendesk.com/external/zenbox/v2.5/zenbox.js"></script>
```

I encounter the problem below when i try to hit Next button, with no text input. Two validation appear: one below the input tag (the tool tip) and one with red on left side(Oops, this seems to be invalid.).

Has anybody knows a fix for this issue, to only show the tool tip without the left red text validaiotn?

[image]

The image above is showed after i click Ask Us button.

Comment: Same problem, searching for resolution. Tried upgrading to v2.6, but that didn't solve the problem.